# javascript, jquery, plupload is it possible to pass a parameter to the URL on the fly without reloading the page/object

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I recently inherated a project that has plupload embeded in it. However I am running into an issue where I want the script change the URL of the object after its been loaded but I am not sure if thats possibe, and if it is, what would I be looking at to do it? Anyone familiar with plupload who can help me figure this out would be awesome!

currently when the page loads it loads with URL: something.php?pth=/&token=fajkljflkaj

the pth= part is the piece im looking to edit on the fly however i can only seem to get it to update only upon the pages load as thats how the object loads its built from what I can tell to be kinda hard coded in not altered on the fly with JavaScript through other means.But I could be wrong. Im open to suggestion

Comment: Could you explain with more detail what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to change the URL from where the plupload SWF/Silverlight object loads or the URL to where files need to be POSTed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can add additional parameters to image upload post request:

```
uploader.settings.multipart_params = { a: 1 };
```